# Setting background picture behind JFrame content in Java

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe

So I'm creating a pinball game. I want a background picture to appear behind the menu system. As of right now, my menu system looks like this (without any background picture)

[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y41uQ.png)

and the code for it:

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

JFrame frame;

public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
private Thread thread;
private boolean running = false;
private Handler handler;
private Random r;
private HUD hud;
private Spawn spawner;
private Menu menu;


public enum STATE {
  Menu,
  Help,
  Game

};

public STATE gameState = STATE.Menu;

public Game(){

    //All game objects
    handler = new Handler();
    menu = new Menu(this, handler);
    this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));
    this.addMouseListener(menu);

    AudioPlayer.load();
    AudioPlayer.getMusic("music").loop();

    new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Pinball", this);

    hud = new HUD();
    spawner = new Spawn(handler,hud);
    r = new Random();

    if(gameState == STATE.Game){

    handler.addObject(new Player(WIDTH/2-32, HEIGHT/2-32, ID.Player, handler));        
    //for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy(r.nextInt(WIDTH),r.nextInt(HEIGHT), ID.BasicEnemy,handler));     
    }         
}

public synchronized void start(){
    thread = new Thread(this); //"this" is where the thread is going to be ran
    thread.start();
    running = true;
}
//Killing of the thead
public synchronized void stop(){
try {
    thread.join();
    running = false;
}catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
}

public void run(){
//Setting up the game loop, every game needs a loop!
this.requestFocus(); //Don't need to click on window to activate key control
long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
double delta = 0;
long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
int frames = 0;
while(running){
    long now = System.nanoTime();
    delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
    lastTime = now;
    while(delta >= 1){
        tick();
        delta--;
    }
    if(running)
        try {
            render();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    frames++;

    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
        timer += 1000;
        //System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
        frames = 0;
        }
    }
    stop();
}

private void tick(){
    handler.tick();

    if(gameState == STATE.Game){
    hud.tick();
    spawner.tick();

    }else if(gameState == STATE.Menu){
        menu.tick();   
    }


}
private void render() throws IOException{

    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }


    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();


    //-------------------------------------
    //Background color
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0,0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    //-------------------------------------


    handler.render(g);

    if(gameState == STATE.Game){

    hud.render(g);

    }else if(gameState == STATE.Menu){
        menu.render(g);


    }else if(gameState == STATE.Menu.Help || gameState == STATE.Help){
        menu.render(g);

    }

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public static int clamp(int var, int min, int max){
    if(var >= max)
        return var = max;
    else if (var <= min)
        return var = min;
    else 
        return var;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   new Game();  
   }  
}
```

I also have another class called Window.java

```
public class Window extends Canvas {


public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.setMaximumSize  (new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.setMinimumSize  (new Dimension(width, height));

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);


    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    //Adding game class into the frame
    frame.add(game);
    game.start();
    }

}
```

So, if I try to put in the code that shows the background picture in the Window class, the background picture is getting in front of the entire menu system.

The "background picture" code in the Window class looks like this:

```
public class Window extends Canvas {


public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

    try {
    frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("C:/res/pinball.png")))));

    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.setMaximumSize  (new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.setMinimumSize  (new Dimension(width, height));

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);


    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    //Adding game class into the frame
    frame.add(game);


    game.start();
    }

}
```

The result is this:

[Background picture in the frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X621.png)

How do I get the picture to appear behind the actual menu system?

My Menu(system) class code looks like this:

```
public class Menu extends MouseAdapter {

//JFrame frame;
private Game game;
private Handler handler;
private Random r = new Random();
public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;

public Menu(Game game, Handler handler){
    this.game = game;
    this.handler = handler;

}
//When you click play it takes you over to the game
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    int mx = e.getX();
    int my = e.getY();




    if(game.gameState == STATE.Menu){

         //Play button
    if(mouseOver(mx, my, 210, 150, 200, 64)){
        game.gameState = STATE.Game;
        handler.addObject(new Player(Game.WIDTH/2-32, Game.HEIGHT/2-32, ID.Player, handler));
        handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy(r.nextInt(WIDTH),r.nextInt(HEIGHT), ID.BasicEnemy,handler));

    }
    //Help button
    if(mouseOver(mx, my, 210, 250,200,64)){
        game.gameState = STATE.Help;

    }



    //Quit button
    if(mouseOver(mx, my, 210, 350, 200, 63)){
        System.exit(1);
        }

     }

           //Back button for help
    if(game.gameState == STATE.Help){
        if(mouseOver(mx, my, 210, 350, 200, 64)){
            game.gameState = STATE.Menu;

        }
    }
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){

}

//Method for checking if mouse is over a button in the menu
private boolean mouseOver(int mx, int my, int x, int y, int width, int height){
    if(mx > x && mx < x + width){
        if(my > y && my < y + height){
            return true;
        }else return false;

    }else return false;




public void tick() {

}

public void render(Graphics g){

    if(game.gameState == STATE.Menu){   

    Font fnt = new Font("Arial", 1, 50);
    Font fnt2 = new Font("Arial", 1, 30);


    g.setFont(fnt);
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.drawString("Menu", 240, 70);

    g.setFont(fnt);
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.drawRect(210,150, 200, 64);
    g.drawString("Play", 265, 200);

    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.drawRect(210,250, 200, 64);
    g.drawString("Help", 265, 300);

    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.drawRect(210,350, 200, 64);
    g.drawString("Quit", 265, 400);  

    }else if(game.gameState == STATE.Help) {
        Font fnt = new Font("Arial", 1, 50);
        Font fnt2 = new Font("Arial", 1, 30);
        Font fnt3 = new Font("Arial", 1, 20);

        g.setFont(fnt);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.drawString("Help", 240, 70);

        g.setFont(fnt3);
        g.drawString("Use WASD keys to move player and dodge enemies", 60,200);
        g.drawRect(210,350, 200, 64);
        g.drawString("Back", 265, 400);        
    }
```

Comment: 1) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Were you intending to post an MCVE / SSCCE any time soon?